# Cannot tag an interface for a specific VLAN : % Error: Tagged flag mis-match Te 0/3

Tags: vlan, trunk, dell

I trying to tag an interface for a specific VLAN on a Dell S4810 :

```
S4810#show run int ten 0/3
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet 0/3
 no ip address
 mtu 12000
 switchport
 flowcontrol rx on tx on
 no shutdown
S4810#conf t
S4810(conf)#int vlan 1616
S4810(conf-if-vl-1616)#tagged tengigabitethernet 0/3
% Error: Tagged flag mis-match Te 0/3.
S4810(conf-if-vl-1616)#
```

I did a `show vlan` but could find that interface in the output :

```
S4810#show vlan | grep "Te 0/3($|,|\))"
S4810#
```

Can you help me ?

EDIT0 : Found it, the port was already untagged in the VLAN1 :

```
S4810#show vlan | grep "Te 0/([0-9]*-)?3($|,|\))"
                                                     U Te 0/2-3,26
S4810#conf t
S4810(conf)#int vlan 1
S4810(conf-if-vl-1)#no untagged tengigabitethernet 0/3
S4810(conf-if-vl-1)#int vlan 1616
S4810(conf-if-vl-1616)#tagged tengigabitethernet 0/3
S4810(conf-if-vl-1616)#end
S4810#wr
!

S4810#
```

Comment: Have you tried the configuration from within the `vlan 1616` configuration instead of the SVI's (`int vlan 1616`)?

Comment: @Zac67 On a Dell switch that `S4810(conf)#vlan 1616` does not work, it says :
`% Error: Invalid input at "^" marker.` I have used the SVI : `int vlan 1616`